# HDMI: What is the maximum acceptable differential impedance variation and for which length

Tags: pcb-design, differential, impedance-matching, high-speed, hdmi

Imagine I have a HDMI bus with differential impedance 100 Ohm and length 10cm

Imagine that for a segment of length "L" there is an impedance variation of "DELTA"

Question: in order to still get an in-spec HDMI eye at the end, which are the max "L" and "DELTA" parameters? how they are related?

I guess this should be simulated with SPICE, anyone has done this execise, any IEEE paper with this info? Impossible to find a reference on the web

Comment: You have to first lock down several assumptions so you can isolate the effect of JUST the impedance variation & length of the line on the eye diagram.  Such as: a specific TMDS data rate, 100% ideal source generation, lossless transmission line, no crosstalk, no cable equalization at the sink.  Then you can probably whip up a SPICE simulation of a single TMDS channel where you step through L and DELTA to try and figure out the "breaking" points.